# Controlling Width of DIV with Browser Height using CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

First off check out my Test Page here:
http://www.joblesspunkdesigns.com/stackoverflow/main/

What I am trying to do is control the width of a DIV with the browsers height using CSS. I don’t want to use Javascript, Jquery, or any other language.

As you can see from my test page, if you scale the browser from a height of 200px to 840px my “contentwrapper” DIV scales accordingly. I have done this with 34 @media queries every 20px… not the best way to do this, but as you can see, it works... sort of...

My END goal is to have everything in the “contentwrapper” DIV always be Vertically and Horizontally centered as well as re-size to make sure all the content in the “contentwrapper” DIV will always be visible without the need of a scroll bar.

Does anyone know a viable way to achieve what I am trying to do?

thank you for your help!

```
/*HTML*/

<div class="content">
    <div class="contentwrapper">
        <img class="carousel" src="img/projectimage_placeholder.jpg"/>
        <h2>Project Name</h2>
        <div class="carouselnav"></div>
    </div>
</div>


/*CSS*/

.contentwrapper {
left: 1.25rem;
right: 1.25rem;
margin: 0 auto;
}

@media all and (min-height:200px) {
.contentwrapper {
width: 149px;
margin-top: 0.3%;
}}

@media all and (min-height:220px) {
.contentwrapper {
width: 154px;
margin-top: 1.5%;
}}

@media all and (min-height:240px) {
.contentwrapper {
width: 170px;
margin-top: 1.5%;
}}
```

and so on, and so on....

Answer (score 0):

If you were so inclined to use a jQuery solution, You would simply need to take advantage of the `.resize()` event or a combination of `.outerWidth()` and `.outerHeight()`.

I suggest you start [here](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) and formulate a plan that works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
.content {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.contentwrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2SEXG/) )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with vertical centering, but you should be able to get this working from here:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="l-table">
        <div class="l-table--cell">
            <div class="l-table--center">
                <article>
                COntent
                </article>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

/******** Main Layout Blocks ********/
html,
body
  // To avoid scrollbar
  height: 100%

.container
  // ^ needs to get 100% height as well
  height: 100% 
  margin:       auto
  max-width:    800px
  overflow-y: auto


/******** Layout-Classes for centering ********/
.l-table
  display: table
  height: 100%
  .lt-ie8 &
    // Polyfill for IE7 applied with parent selector
  //  behavior: url(polyfills/display-table.min.htc)

.l-table--cell
  display: table-cell
  vertical-align: middle

.l-table--center
  margin: 0 auto
```

http://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/jrGdq

and another layout with this technique:
http://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/bmlnD

Comment: Very interesting work you have, this achieve 1 of the 2 problems. I want the content to not have a scroll bar and re-size to fit the browser screen. Review my Test page again, or check out arieljuod hack bellow (I made a test page of that too in my comment). But thank you for the vertical center solution! :)

Comment: You mean it should get larger vertically, if there is not enough space?

Comment: Part1.) I would like the content to scale accordingly to the browser window and all content within the contentwrapper DIV always be visible  without a scroll bar. Part2.) The contentwrapper DIV should always be vertically and horizontally centered.

Comment: Yap I got that, but what should happen if there is not enough space? Do you want the container to scale up? You cold also set a width and height of 100%, if you desire. Its not quite clear to me how you would like to get there.

Comment: In your Demo you are dealing with Text, which if I had that much text I would set @media at break points to deal with the font size scaling down. Since with my project, I'm only dealing with 3 elements (img, h2, div) within this DIV, so there will always be enough space to show everything without any scroll bars. The only situation where I would not have enough space would be something crazy small like 100px by 100px display. If the DIV did get too small to display the content (again, we are talking about a non-usable scale) then the content overflow would be set to overflow: hidden;

Comment: Like this: http://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/jrGdq ??

if the image might be to large under certain circumstances you could use @media(max-width) & and @media(max-height)

Comment: Hmm, close! :) As you mentioned the image will be to large under certain circumstances. That's why I'm trying to use the browser height to re-size the contentwrapper DIV so that the image and other content within will scale accordingly. Also, like you said, we both came to the same dead-end of using @ media to scale the img (div in my case). Doing so "smoothly" I had to create 34 @media queries.. yeah it worked..kinda, but not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Well you have to use either javascript or media queries, because there is no other way to let the container know that it should be smaller for such a specific case. If you use the table-technique it shouldn't be necessary to use 34

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I've done something similar once with a little hack. Browsers maintain images aspect ratio when you only set with side's size and leave the other side as "auto". So, using a weird hack you can depend on that. I don't have the code right now but this is the idea:

you have the div that you want to respect some ratio according to the height, lets say it's a div with ID 'wrapper', so, your css would be something like:

```
#wrapper {
  height: 80%; //use what you need to make the height relative
}
```

then inside that wrapper you will have 2 things: an inline-block transparent image with the ratio you want and an absolute positioned div where your content will be:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
  <img src='mi_inivisible_hack.png' id='invisible_hack' alt='' />
  <div id='wrapper_content'>Your content here</div>
</div>
```

now the css would be:

```
#wrapper {
  height: 80%;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#invisible_hack {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

#wrapper_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Now, when you resize your window, #wrapper will be smaller, then the image must get smaller and #wrapper will shrink to it's content (the image) respecting your ratio. Then #wrapper_content will shrink too because it goes from 0 left to 0 right and 0 top to 0 bottom.

It's a little hack, but I think it works great and fluid.

Comment: Wow!
I’ve been testing this out all morning and it this is a mighty fine hack you have found. 

Test Page, let me know if something is wrong:
http://www.joblesspunkdesigns.com/stackoverflow/arieljuod/test1.html

That said, this is dang close to what I need, but I found some bugs that won’t allow me to use it:

a. For some reason shrinking the height is only triggered when you grab the corner of the browser window, not just the bottom.

b. I could only get it working in Safari/Chrome. Did not work in FF, and didn't test IE.

Comment: That said I applaud you for finding this nifty hack, it does seem to work pretty dang well! but some limitations make it not as stable as I’m looking for…. but do you know of anyway of optimizing this idea? I would love to expand this concept a bit more to have it stable enough to work 100% of the time :D

Answer (score 0):

As stated below - Wouldn't using percentages instead of pixel values suit you well?